# Normalize multiple columns of list/tuple data

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples, normalization

I have a dataframe with multiple columns of tuple data. I'm trying to normalize the data within the tuple for each row per columns. This is an example with lists, but it should be the same concept for tuples as well-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 10), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
df['arr1'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].values.tolist()
df['arr2'] = df[['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']].values.tolist()
```

If I wish to normalize each list row for a few columns, I would do this-

```
df['arr1'] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df['arr1']]
df['arr2'] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df['arr2']]
```

However, since I have about 100 such columns in my original dataset, I obviously don't want to manually normalize per column. How can I loop across all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look through columns in a DataFrame like this to process each column:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df[col]]
```

Of course, this only works if you want to process *all* of the columns in the DataFrame. If you only want a subset, you could create a list of columns first, or you could drop the other columns.

```py
# Here's an example where you manually specify the columns
cols_to_process = ["arr1", "arr2"]

for col in cols_to_process:
    df[col] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df[col]]


# Here's an example where you drop the unwanted columns first
cols_to_drop = ["a", "b", "c"]
df = df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)

for col in cols_to_process:
    df[col] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df[col]]


# Or, if you didn't want to actually drop the columns
# from the original DataFrame you could do it like this:
cols_to_drop = ["a", "b", "c"]
for col in df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop):
    df[col] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df[col]]
```